# On which date was this photo taken?

Tags: knowledge, real

On which date was this photo taken? Here are your clues:

- A simple, handheld camera phone faithfully captured what the eye saw. No artificial filters, lighting or trick photography was used.
- It was a Monday in this millennium.
- The DJIA closed at *****.75

[image]

Photo credit: Mrs. Flanman

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer could be

> Monday August 21, 2017

Because

> Oddly enough, I have this as my Facebook banner pic
>  [image]

> It was taken during the solar eclipse. I did edit my picture a little to look better. It was a fun day at work.
>  A quick search gives me: Dow Jones Industrial Average ( DJIA ) Close  - 21703.75
>  EDIT - The eclipse I witnessed was called the [Great American Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_August_21,_2017).

Comment: Just now realized that your profile picture is not a smiling face! :):)

Comment: @Voldemort’sWrath, it’s an illusion. I’m actually always frowning. Jk. It’s my family coat of arms.

Comment: Why do these curves occur?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky, I guess it's a visualization of the moon passing in front of the sun. I don't know the exact science behind it. You do it by poking holes in a piece of paper or card stock and then projecting that hole onto another piece of paper. OP must have had a bunch of holes poked in his top paper (which is out of frame in his picture)

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky, better yet, the trees he was under may have had a lot of little gaps of sunlight that projected multiple images. I think the hole shape projects to a circle regardless of the hole shape.

Comment: It must be tiny holes.

Comment: @FlorianF, I just Google Imaged "eclipse through leaves." wow. That is an awesome idea. - edit-  I kinda want to try it during the next one. Not sure when that will be though.

Comment: I was sure it was an old sheet overhead with small holes.  But it seems that leaves naturally try to catch all sunlight and leave only small individual holes, each producing an image of the sun.

Comment: The crescent-shaped light occurred naturally as the sunlight filtered through gaps in the leaves above the camera while the sun was about 90% eclipsed by the moon. It's a en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_obscura effect.